# Append a .js file in AIR

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, air

I have an application that, in a browser, gets a .js file from the server with some functions declared, appends this file to its head section, and then calls the functions at some points in the app.

I want to reproduce this behaviour in AIR, but the append stuff is not working (it seems like I get the file, but I cant access/append its content). How would you work around that ? (I cannot code the js directly because it s dynamically changing depending on server stuff).

Comment: It's been a few years since I've worked with AIR, but as I recall, it doesn't suffer from the Same Origin Policy like browsers do.  Therefore, you ought to be able to issue an XMLHttpRequest(), grab the data, and eval() it to get access to what you want.  I remember AIR placing some restrictions on when and where you can eval(), but you *should* be able to do it in some fashion.

Comment: I ve been through that ;) thing is : AIR won't allow eval. I found some workarounds when I needed eval, but my problem is different here : I don't want to run a query, I want to load a .js containing functions, that I *could* use later. So without eval() I'm stuck.

Comment: Yeah, Adobe's stance on security is one of the principal reasons I abandoned AIR back in 2007.  As I recall though, they were working on a sandbox model where in one box you could download remote code, eval, etc, and in the other box you could access the filesystem, do SQL, etc.  So in effect, there were two zones, and there was an API allowing some amount of invocation between them.  Adobe's main security goal (as I understand it) is to only allow code to run which the user has specifically allowed by installing the app, and deny all else (such as downloaded remote code).

Comment: okkkk thanks a lot for this point of view ! Because they have such a flexible approach of the Same Origin Policy, I thought it'd be easy to include .js... I'll look into the sandbox thing, thanks. I really thought I was crazy/stupid, looking at theirs docs and seeing them do it all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f0e.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ef9

turns out it is not possible.

As stated by jimbojw, "sandboxes" turnarounds are possible (cf. link above)